# Image upload in firebase database gives "NAN" in file upload progress

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-storage

Upload progress value on state change in firebase, but it is returning "Nan" 
when i print progress value.

So how can we get number instead of 'NAN'

```
function getfile() {

  const ref = firebase.storage().ref('images/');
  const file = $('#file-upload').get(0).files[0];
  const name = (+new Date()) + '-' + file.name;
  const metadata = {
    contentType: file.type
  };
  const task = ref.child(name).put(file, metadata);

  task.on('state_changed',

      function progress(snapshot) {
        var percentage =
          (snapshot.byteTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100;

        console.log(percentage);
      },

      function error(err) {

      },

      function complete() {
        console.log('Submited Sucessfully');

      }
```

Comment: Don't you think that it should be `snapshot.bytesTransferred` instead of `snapshot.byteTransferred` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to firebase [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/upload-files) the correct property is **bytesTransferred** to get

> The total number of bytes that have been transferred when this snapshot was taken.

Looking to your code the reason for the error is that there is typo in your code.

The code is using by mistake:

`snapshot.byteTransferred`

instead of the correct:

`snapshot.bytesTransferred`

The property which your code is accessing gives you `undefined` which results in `NAN` in the console because this property is not present within TaskSnapshot object is passed back.